# Stata / Loops to delete every 9th-15th observation out of 15,000 observations

Tags: loops, stata

I am trying to create a loop that deletes every 9th-15th observations out of dataset containing around 15,000 observations.  What would be the syntax?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, but please just focus on the technical question you have. Your need is not a criterion.

Comment: The real question is given in a comment below my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should not loop over observations as there is almost definitely a more efficient and elegant solution, as Nick noted above with the `drop if missing(turnout)` solution. However, I gather you are a new Stata user so I will run through a hypothetical. Suppose that you in fact did want to `drop` observations within a certain range rather than based on a secondary variable like `turnout`. The general strategy could be as follows:

1. Group observations in groups of 15 (which I think you have here with the `id` column). In the solution below I will assume you do not have this column.
2. Within each group, `drop` the observations in the 9th-15th places.

```
// Group observations
gen group = ceil(_n/15)
// Within each group, drop in the 9-15 locations 
by group: drop if inrange(_n,9,15)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
drop if mod(_n, 9) == 0
```

will `drop` observations 9, 18, 27, and so forth. The same principle applies to any other positive integer.

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't quite working for some reason. if you take a look at the image I shared, I'm trying to delete observations that don't have the values for the variable "turnout".

Comment: `drop if missing(turnout)`